# Python 2.7 Remove special chac, spacing BUT NOT CHINESE CHARACTERS

Tags: python-2.7

```
string = "Special $#! characters   spaces 888323 Kek  ཌི ༜ 郭 ༜  དྀ    "
```

**result should be :** "Specialcharactersspaces888323Kek郭"

**i have tried with**
`print ''.join(c for c in string.decode('utf-8') if u'\u4e00' <= c <= u'\u9fff')`

**but error return**
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u90ed' in position 4
9: ordinal not in range(128)`

my question is same as title,
Remove special chac, spacing BUT NOT CHINESE CHARACTERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) and [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) functions:

```
import re

string = "Special $#! characters   spaces 888323 Kek  ཌི ༜ 郭 ༜  དྀ    "

# defining the pattern which should match all characters excepting alphanumeric and chinese
pattern = re.compile(u'[^a-z0-9⺀-⺙⺛-⻳⼀-⿕々〇〡-〩〸-〺〻㐀-䶵一-鿃豈-鶴侮-頻並-龎]', re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)
result = pattern.sub('', string)

# print(result)  Python v.3 printing
print result
```

The output:

```
Specialcharactersspaces888323Kek郭
```

Comment: how about i dont want to delete symbol like '$#!?<>' @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: exception special chac like !@#$%^&*():"<>/.

Comment: @ChinYe, show the expected result according to your "exception list"

Comment: 'Special$#!charactersspaces888323Kek郭' like this

Comment: just add those characters to the pattern character class and it will work for your new case: `pattern = re.compile(u'[^a-z0-9!@#$%^&*():"<>/.⺀-⺙⺛-⻳⼀-⿕々〇〡-〩〸-〺〻㐀-䶵一-鿃豈-鶴侮-頻並-龎]', re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)`